# Discrete Probabilities

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of discrete real random variables defined over the same probabilistic space. Let $\{a_n\} _n$ be a sequence such that $\lim_n a_n = \infty$. By hypothesis we have that

\begin{equation} \nonumber
\lim_n \mathbb{P} (X_{n_0} = a_{n} ) =0,
\end{equation}

for all $n_0\in\mathbb{N} $. My question is whether or not we have

\begin{equation} \nonumber
\lim_n \mathbb{P} (X_n = a_n) = 0.
\end{equation}.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_n$ be the random variable which takes on the value $n$ at all times. Define $a_n := n$. Then

$$\lim_n \mathbb{P} (X_n = a_n) = \lim_n  1 = 1. $$